# Using the Struts2-Rest-Plugin with Spring

Tags: spring, struts2, struts2-spring-plugin

I'm starting to use the Struts2 Rest Plugin in our Spring application.
Let's start with our **struts.xml**:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="lang/messages" />
    <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="rest" />

    <package name="default">
        <action name="document" class="DocumentRestaction" />
    </package>
</struts>
```

Then in Spring, I'm doing the following (to see if the String is injected):

```
<bean name="DocumentRestaction" class="be.example.actions.DocumentRestaction">
    <property name="injected" value="Oh Hai" />
</bean>
```

I do a `POST` request to the URL `/documents` and end up in the `create()` method, great! In debug, my `injected` variable is injected. But when I let the debug continue, I get following exception:

```
4129 [http-8080-2] ERROR org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation - Exception processing the result.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid action class configuration that references an unknown class named [DocumentRestaction]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionsServiceImpl.determineResultPath(ConventionsServiceImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.determinePath(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:379)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionUnknownHandler.handleUnknownResult(ConventionUnknownHandler.java:268)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.handleUnknownResult(DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:227)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.executeResult(RestActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.processResult(RestActionInvocation.java:198)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.invoke(RestActionInvocation.java:146)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.execute(DefaultActionProxy.java:147)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DocumentRestaction
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.struts2.util.ClassLoaderUtils.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtils.java:111)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ConventionsServiceImpl.determineResultPath(ConventionsServiceImpl.java:98)
    ... 27 more
```

But the class has been found .. (I ended up in `create`), why is it saying this? And most importantly, what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Spring v3.0.5, struts2-rest-plugin v2.3.1, struts2-core v2.3.1 and struts2-spring-plugin 2.3.1

Comment: Are you also using the S2 spring plugin?

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention that normal Struts actions work with Spring already

Comment: Okay. Yeah, I suspect it's flailing when it tries to determine the result path, although I don't have an immediate workaround. I'd file a JIRA for this against the REST plugin if there isn't one already; it may be a known issue, but I don't have an answer at this point--someone will look in to it.

Comment: Also, which version are you using?

Comment: Confirmed; there's an apparent (one more thing to check) conflict between how the convention plugin looks up the result path (based on the class) and the spring plugin. Note that configuring via autowiring would likely eliminate the problem--I believe the issue happens specifically because you're configuring it in XML.

Comment: Ah, thanks for looking this up! I'll try to configure it by using `properties` and autowiring and update my question with my results

Comment: Ah, I solved the problem by removing the convention plugin! This is unnecessary as you're using Spring to instantiate your Class instances!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a solution to this, [this](http://blog.mersoft.com/2009/09/08/struts2-rest-webservice/#spring) article might help.

There's an omission in the sample code given though - in your applicationContext.xml, make sure you define the "id" and "class" to be the fully qualified class name of your controller:

```
   <bean id="com.mersoft.web.controller.TestController" class="com.mersoft.web.controller.TestController">
      <constructor-arg ref="testManager" />
   </bean>
```

Hope that helps. Oh, and to be clear, you don't have to remove the convention plugin as suggested in an earlier comment.